# I'm working on an app, the app has to push a notification at a specific time but its not working

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an app(basically a todo list), it has to push a notification at a specific time of how many tasks are remaining. But its not pushing any notification. I'm new to android.

here is the MainActivity

```
package dev.amanraj.ListUp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import dev.amanraj.ListUp.Adapter.ToDoAdapter;
import dev.amanraj.ListUp.Model.ToDoModel;
import dev.amanraj.ListUp.Utils.DatabaseHandler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogCloseListener{

    private RecyclerView tasksRecyclerView;
    private ToDoAdapter tasksAdapter;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private List<ToDoModel> taskList;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView progressText;
    private ImageView hint_tap, hint_right, hint_left;

    private static final String TAG = "Alarm";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hint_tap = findViewById(R.id.tap_hint);
        hint_left = findViewById(R.id.left_hint);
        hint_right = findViewById(R.id.right_hint);
        hint_tap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hint_tap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hint_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        hint_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hint_right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hint_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        hint_left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hint_left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });



//        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        db.openDatabase();

//        taskList = new ArrayList<>();

        tasksRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.tasksRecyclerView);
        tasksRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        tasksAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(db,MainActivity.this);
        tasksRecyclerView.setAdapter(tasksAdapter);

        fab=findViewById(R.id.fab);
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(tasksAdapter));
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(tasksRecyclerView);
        taskList = db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.setTasks(taskList);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressText = findViewById(R.id.progressText);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddNewTask.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),AddNewTask.TAG);
            }
        });
        updateProgress();
        setAlarm();
    }

    //update progress method
    private void updateProgress(){
        int totalTasks = taskList.size();
        int completedTasks = 0;
        for (ToDoModel task : taskList){
            if (task.getStatus() == 1){
                completedTasks++;
            }
        }
        if (totalTasks > 0){
            int progress = (completedTasks*100)/totalTasks;
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            progressText.setText(progress + "%");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void handleDialogClose(DialogInterface dialog){
        taskList = db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.setTasks(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //updating progress when task changes
        updateProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskStatusChanged(){
        updateProgress();
    }


    private void setAlarm(){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        //setting the alarm to start at 8pm

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
        Log.d(TAG,"Alarm set");
        //scheduling the alarm to repeat daily
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

and here is the AlarmReceiver that I've made

```
package dev.amanraj.ListUp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

import dev.amanraj.ListUp.Model.ToDoModel;
import dev.amanraj.ListUp.Utils.DatabaseHandler;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG,"Alarm received");
        //getting the remaining tasks
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.openDatabase();
        List<ToDoModel> tasks = db.getAllTasks();
        int remainingTasks = 0;
        for (ToDoModel task : tasks){
            if (task.getStatus() == 0){
                //assuming 0 represents unchecked tasks
                remainingTasks++;
            }
        }
        db.close();

        //sending Notification
        sendNotification(context ,remainingTasks);
    }

    private void sendNotification(Context context, int remainingTasks){
        Log.d(TAG,"Sending notification");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //creating a notification channel if the device is running Android 8 or higher
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            Log.d(TAG,"creating notification channel");
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("task_notification_channel", "Task Notification Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        //creating the notification
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context,"task_notification_channel")
                .setContentTitle("Remaining tasks")
                .setContentText("You have " + remainingTasks + " tasks remaining.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        //showing the notification
        notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
    }


}
```

I've added multiple logs in both the code, The Log in MainActivity does appear in the logcat, but logs from AlarmReceiver doen't shows up.
need help

Comment: did you add the notification  permission in the manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the causes could be the following

1 you need to declare in your app's manifest file

```
`<manifest ...>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


<application ...>

    ...
</application>
```

`
2 you need to create the NotificationChannel with something like this

```
`// Create the NotificationChannel.
    val name = ctext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_name)
    val descriptionText = ctext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_description)
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = ctext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_name)
    val mChannel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
    mChannel.description = descriptionText
    // Register the channel with the system. You can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this.
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)`
```

3 you need to create a notification with something like this

```
`val builder = Notification.Builder(ctext,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.heart)
            .setContentTitle(titleToBeNotified)
            .setContentText(rextToBeNotified)
            // Set the intent that fires when the user taps the notification.
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap1)
            .setStyle(Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(bitmap1))
        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctext)) {
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define.
            notify(1, builder.build())
        }`
```

See https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications