Sending a notification based on inputs from an android studio Bluetooth terminal app taking inputs from Arduino
I need to make an app for my Arduino project that takes inputs from sensor readings, transmits those inputs to an HC-05 Arduino Bluetooth module, the Bluetooth serial terminal app receives the data from the Bluetooth module and sends a notification based on those inputs.
The notification didn't seem to work at all, I don't know why... I would be grateful if someone helped. (I'm not good at java at all)
This is the simple Bluetooth terminal GitHub repository: https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothTerminal.
I opened the project in Android Studio and modified the code so that while getting the inputs, it also creates a string and filters the string based on the data format from the HC-05 module.
What was expected was for the app to send a notification if either of the 3 values exceeded their threshold, it didn't do that however.
This is the entire Arduino code (skip this, it's not really important):
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "Adafruit_Sensor.h"
#include "DHT.h"
#include <MQ2.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <BH1750.h>

#define DHTIN_PIN 2
#define DHTOUT_PIN 3
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

SoftwareSerial B(10, 11);
DHT dhtin = DHT(DHTIN_PIN, DHTTYPE);
DHT dhtout = DHT(DHTOUT_PIN, DHTTYPE);
MQ2 mq2(A0);
int fan = 4;
int LED = 5;
int Valve = 6;
BH1750 lightMeter;

void setup() 
{
  B.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  dhtin.begin();
  dhtout.begin();

  mq2.begin();

  lightMeter.begin();
  Wire.begin();
  if (lightMeter.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("BH1750 initialised"));
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(F("Error initialising BH1750"));
  }

  pinMode(fan, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Valve, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);
  float t_in = dhtin.readTemperature();
  float t_out = dhtout.readTemperature();
  float t_diff = t_out - t_in;

  float LPG = mq2.readLPG();

  uint16_t lux = lightMeter.readLightLevel();

  int AnalogGas = analogRead(A5);


  if (AnalogGas >= 300)               
  {
    digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Valve, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Valve, HIGH);
  }

  if (lux <= 300)               
  {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }


  if (isnan(t_in) || isnan(t_out)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println(t_in);
  Serial.println(" C Inside");
  Serial.print(t_out);
  Serial.println(" C outside");
  Serial.print(t_diff);
  Serial.println(" C diff");
  Serial.print(LPG);
  Serial.println(" PPM");
  Serial.println(AnalogGas); 
  Serial.print(" ohm");
  Serial.print("nan");
  Serial.println("ohm");
  Serial.println("----------------------");
  String BluetoothData = String(t_diff) + " C_diff " + String(LPG) + " PPM " + String(lux) + " lux";
  B.println(BluetoothData);
  delay(200);
}

this is the HC-05 Bluetooth data format that it's supposed to send to the app for short:
String BluetoothData = String(t_diff) + " C_diff " + String(LPG) + " PPM " + String(lux) + " lux";
  B.println(BluetoothData);
  delay(200);

as for the app code, I tweaked the app a little bit for the notification, I made a Java class file for the notification, and called the class based on the inputs:
This is the main part which I modified in the terminal java file, TerminalFragment.java:
    private void send(String str) {
        if(connected != Connected.True) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            String msg;
            byte[] data;
            if(hexEnabled) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                TextUtil.toHexString(sb, TextUtil.fromHexString(str));
                TextUtil.toHexString(sb, newline.getBytes());
                msg = sb.toString();
                data = TextUtil.fromHexString(msg);
            } else {
                msg = str;
                data = (str + newline).getBytes();
                String[] inputs = msg.split(" ");

                NotificationPrompt Notification1 = new NotificationPrompt();
                if (Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]) < 3) {
                    Notification1.DHT22(getActivity());
                }

                if (Integer.parseInt(inputs[2]) > 300) {
                    Notification1.BH1750(getActivity());
                }

                if (Integer.parseInt(inputs[4]) > 1000) {
                    Notification1.MQ2(getActivity());
                }
            }

            SpannableStringBuilder spn = new SpannableStringBuilder(msg + '\n');
            spn.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSendText)), 0, spn.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            receiveText.append(spn);
            service.write(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            onSerialIoError(e);
        }
    }

And this is the main code of the java file I added, the notificationprompt.java file:
package de.kai_morich.simple_bluetooth_terminal;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotificationPrompt {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public static void BH1750(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Alert")
                .setContentText("Natural light detected, taking action....")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }
    public static void DHT22(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Alert")
                .setContentText("Temperature difference is below 3 degrees")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }
    public static void MQ2(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Alert")
                .setContentText("Gas leak detected, Taking action...")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }

}

The app runs fine and well and receives the data, it just doesn't send anything when the data goes the given threshold in the if statements.
I'd be grateful for anyone's help, and thanks in advance.

did you put uses-permission "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" in the manifest? see my answer [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78247289/im-working-on-an-app-the-app-has-to-push-a-notification-at-a-specific-time-but/78247997#78247997)

Yep:

